# Javascript & PHP handling

Tags: javascript, php, display, retain

I'm trying to do following - 
1) Create a quiz that fetches questions from a database
2) Prints out score after checking for response from user against correct response in DB
3) Retain values of user on final display screen.

New to php & js. PHP works fine but JS just doesn't retain the values.

Code for reference -

```
<html> 
    <head> 
        <style type="text/css"> 
            .End input[type="radio"]:checked + label {color: green;}
        </style>
    </head> 

    <body> 
        <form action = "" method="post" id="form"> 
            <table>

                <?php 
                $servername = "localhost"; 
                $username = "root"; 
                $password = "mysql"; 
                $dbname = "ugc";

                // Create connection 
                $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname); 

                // Check connection 
                if ($conn->connect_error) 
                    { die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error); }

                //Extract Data 
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM question_bank WHERE category = 'Maths' "; $result = $conn->query($sql);

                $num_ques = 0; 
                $count = 0;

                if ($result->num_rows > 0 && $num_ques <= 10) 
                    { 
                        // output data of each row 
                        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
                            {
                            $id = $row["ID"]; 
                            $question = $row["Question"]; 
                            $a = $row["Option_A"]; 
                            $b = $row["Option_B"]; 
                            $c = $row["Option_C"]; 
                            $d = $row["Option_D"]; 
                            $correct = $row["Correct"]; 
                            $num_ques += 1; 
                            $temp="G".$num_ques;
                ?>

               <tr><td><?php echo $num_ques.") "; ?><td><?php echo $question; ?></td></tr>

               <tr><td><input type="radio" name="G<?php echo $num_ques; ?>" value="a" id="first" />
                   <label for="first"><?php echo $a; ?></label><br/></td></tr> 
               <tr><td><input type="radio" name="G<?php echo $num_ques; ?>" value="b" id="second" />
                   <label for="second"><?php echo $b; ?></label><br/></td></tr> 
               <tr><td><input type="radio" name="G<?php echo $num_ques; ?>" value="c" id="third" />
                   <label for="third"><?php echo $c; ?></label><br/></td></tr>
               <tr><td><input type="radio" name="G<?php echo $num_ques; ?>" value="d" id="fourth" />
                   <label for="fourth"><?php echo $d; ?></label><br/></td></tr> 

               <!-- <tr><td><input type="radio" name="G<?php echo $num_ques; ?>" value="d"><?php echo $d; ?></td></tr> --> 
               <tr><td><input type="hidden" name="correct<?php echo $num_ques; ?>" value="<?php echo $correct; ?>"></td></tr>

               <?php } } else { echo "No results"; } $conn->close(); ?>
           </table>

               <input type="hidden" name="total_ques" value="<?php echo $num_ques; ?>">
               <input type="submit" value="End" onSubmit = "return changeColor()"> 
        </form>     

                <?php 
                    $counter =0; 
                    for ($i=1; $i <= $_POST["total_ques"]; $i++) 
                        { 
                            $c = "correct".$i; 
                            $r = "G".$i; 
                            $correct = $_POST[$c]; 
                            $response = $_POST[$r]; 

                            if ($correct == $response) {$counter+=1;}
                        } 
                    echo "Your score = ".$counter; 

                ?>

                    <script> 
                        function changeColor()
                            { 
                                form.classList.add("End");
                                return false;

                            }
                    </script>
    </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: JS just doesn't work. It was working a while ago but then PHP wasn't working. I tried to tweak that around. Now PHP is working but JS is not

Comment: In which situation is it not working? What happens? So your question is: Why is not JS working? You have to be a lot more specific for us to help you.

Comment: It just doesn't run. It is supposed to colour the user response for radio buttons in the form upon submission. But it does nothing of that sort. It's like not having the code at all.

Comment: If you do an alert('x'); in the changeColorÖ() function. Does it show a dialog?

Answer (score 0):

1) It's `onsubmit` not `onSubmit`.

2) The `onsubmit` event applies only on a form tag (ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit_event)

So, you should rename `onSubmit = "return changeColor()"` to `onsubmit = "return changeColor()"`, then move it to the form tag.

Moreover you can't just call `form.classList.add("End");` it will throw an `undefined` error. What is `form` here? It just doesn't exist in this context. There are at least two ways to do this.

First: Pass the form object in the params

```
<form onsubmit="return someFunction(event, this)">
    Enter name: <input type="text">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
<script>
    function someFunction(event, form) {
        form.classList.add('abc');

        return false; //whatever boolean you want, just an example
    }
</script>
```

Here you pass a first argument, which is the event object. Second parameter is this, in this situation it's an object representation of your form. In your JS function you handle both. I called my second argument just `form`. Now I can do actions on my `form` argument which references to my form.

Second is simpler for a beginner. Just give an id to the form and get it by its id.

```
<form id="my-form" onsubmit="return someFunction()">
    Enter name: <input type="text">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
<script>
    function someFunction() {
        let form = document.getElementById('my-form');
        form.classList.add('my-class');

        return false; //whatever boolean you want, just an example
    }
</script>
```

These two examples show you how your could should look like. Of course you have to adopt it to your needs.

I'm not sure if this will solve all your problems. But I'm sure this will at least a part of them.